request X-Openstack-Request-Id is not same as response X-Openstack-Request-Id
when i operate instance with openstack api, the code is as follows:
def stop_server(self, server_id: str):
    api_url = self.endpoint + f'/servers/{server_id}/action'
    json = {"os-stop": None}
    headers = self.get_auth_token_header()
    import uuid
    req_id = f"req-{str(uuid.uuid4())}"
    print(req_id)
    if req_id:
        headers['X-Openstack-Nova-Api-Version'] = '2.46'
        headers['X-Openstack-Request-Id'] = req_id
    resp = self.make_request('post', api_url, json=json, headers=headers)
    print(resp.headers)
    return resp

i specify the global request ID in the request header, but the global ID "X-Openstack-Request-Id" in response header is not same as i specify in the request header.
The API reference is: https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#request-ids
Request IDs
Users can specify the global request ID in the request header. Users can receive the local request ID in the response header.
The global request ID, which is a unique common ID for tracking each request in OpenStack components. The format of the global request ID must be req- + UUID (UUID4). If not in accordance with the format, it is ignored. It is associated with the request and appears in the log lines for that request. By default, the middleware configuration ensures that the global request ID appears in the log files.
New in version 2.46
my X-Openstack-Request-Id is req-600d0d83-92aa-4c08-8e6d-38ea586ab990
response headers is {'Content-Length': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Openstack-Api-Version': 'compute 2.46', 'X-Openstack-Nova-Api-Version': '2.46', 'Vary': 'OpenStack-API-Version, X-OpenStack-Nova-API-Version', 'X-Openstack-Request-Id': 'req-ff3faec2-b72e-4478-a542-d2eda78c467d', 'X-Compute-Request-Id': 'req-ff3faec2-b72e-4478-a542-d2eda78c467d', 'Date': 'Wed, 17 Apr 2024 06:38:05 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
I changed the version of the api and it still doesn't work
